# How to aggregate data by counts of a level, setting each level's counts as its own column?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have data which has a row granularity in terms of events, and I want to aggregate them by a customer ID. The data is in the form of a pandas df and looks like so:

```
| Event ID | Cust ID | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
------------------------------------------

| 1    | 1    | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
--------------------------

| 2    | 1    | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
--------------------------
| 3    | 1    | 10 | 12 | 0 | 0 |
---------------------------    
| 4    | 2    | 206 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
---------------------------    
| 5 | 2 | 206 | 25 | 0 | 0 |
----------------------------
```

P1 to P4 have numbers which are just levels, they are event categories which I need to get counts of (there are 175+ codes), where each event category gets its own column.

The output I want, would ideally look like:

```
| Cust ID | Count(12) | Count(10) | Count(25) | Count(206) |
------------------------------------------------------------    
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
---------------------    
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
---------------------
```

The challenge I am facing is taking the counts across multiple columns. There are 2 '12's in P1 and 1 '12' in P2.

I tried using groupby and merge. But I've either used them incorrectly or they're the wrong functions to use because I get a lot of 'NaN's in the resulting table.

Comment: you can do a `melt(['Event ID','Cust ID'])`, then `groupby().value_counts()`.

Comment: This function works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                  'Cust ID':[1]*3+[2]*2,
                  'P1':[12,12,10,206,25],
                  'P2':[0,0,12,0,0],
                  'P3':[0]*5,
                  'P4':[0]*5})

df.melt(['Event ID','Cust ID'])\
  .groupby('Cust ID')['value'].value_counts()\
  .unstack().add_prefix('Count_')\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
value  Cust ID  Count_0  Count_10  Count_12  Count_25  Count_206
0            1      8.0       1.0       3.0       NaN        NaN
1            2      6.0       NaN       NaN       1.0        1.0
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the solution. It works, but I didn't fully understand how. Are there any resources you could point to where I could learn more? Thanks!

Comment: @KalpakKulkarni Yes, look at my profile.  [DunderData](https://www.dunderdata.com/a/16368/zKnskk2y) has great training material.  And if you get a chance to take one of Ted Petrou's courses, I highly recommend it.

Comment: @KalpakKulkarni would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution.